# New error: could not form projection (PJ) from 'srid=3424' to 'srid=4326'

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to convert a New Jersey sourced dataset to 4326 to append the records to another table. The data source is: https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/njdep::dry-cleaners-of-new-jersey/about

I am getting the file as a CSV and uploading to Postgres

I have done this many times, but this time I am getting the above error. I did recently reinstall Windows as well as Postgres (exact same version as previous), newest PostGIS and newest QGIS.

This is the query I use to create the geom field.

```
Update cleaner set temp_geo=ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || x_coord_num || ' ' || y_coord_num  || ')', 3424) where x_coord_num <> 0 and not x_coord_num is null and y_coord_num <> 0 and not y_coord_num is null
```

And the one that gives the error:

```
Update cleaner set lng=ST_X(ST_Transform(temp_geo, 4326)) where not temp_geo is null
```

Is 3424 deprecated? It is still in my spatial_ref_sys.

I am going to try the GeoJSON download option which may sidestep this issue, but I would like a solution for when I inevitably encounter it again in the future.

Edit:

Just hit another one from Missouri: **could not form projection (PJ) from 'srid=26915' to 'srid=4326'**.

So maybe `ST_Transform` broke somehow?

Edit 2:
This works (SRID of temp_geo is 26915):

`select ST_Transform(temp_geo, 3424) from work_moustlis_2023_q2.ust`

So I can transform between 26915 and 3424 but neither can do 4326.

Something is definitely wrong. If I use the sample form the PostGIS docs for ST_Transform I get the error:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((743238 2967416,743238 2967450,
    743265 2967450,743265.625 2967416,743238 2967416))',2249),4326)) As wgs_geom
```

I did have to change a bunch of environment variable to get OGR2OGR working. I did the same with my last installation and it did not break anything.

Comment: It is not deprecated https://epsg.org/crs_3424/NAD83-New-Jersey-ftUS.html?

Comment: In this mail thread https://www.mail-archive.com/postgis-users@lists.osgeo.org/msg09143.html the same issue was probably due to incompatible libraries.